# How to get out Titans that occupy a planet I own?

Tags: stellaris

The project to investigate titanic life on my newly colonized planet went away and the Titans now occupy the planet.

However, there is no way with my troop to bombard or attack them because they are not on a valid target, they are on my planet. Nothing happens when I try to break the defenses...

Is this situation a a bug? Otherwise, how to get out Titans that occupy a planet I own?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/4i6op5/one_of_my_planets_is_in_having_a_bad_time_titanic/

Comment: Thanks @n_palum , I already read the post, but I'm a little bit confused because it's from last years and there are been a lot a patch since them. Also, this is not really a solution : player put the system into a sector to solve the problem :/

Comment: That was all I was really able to find on the topic as did you I guess. From my own experience, integrating the Titans was the only way to avoid this. I think the Titans taking over and you being unable to take it over is just how it is unfortunately.

Comment: You can write it as answer and I will accept it until there is a bug resolution or a real solution to get rid of them entirely. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Unlikely that it's a legit bug or that it will be fixed as even that reddit post is from 2016

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to get 3 titan armies, but only after the tileblockers appeared and those tileblockers are still there. But, I'm not against teraforming if that will remove them.